# Не инжектит переменную после рестарта активити

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

проблема - есть активити, хранит переменную lateinit database, которая инжектится с помощью Dagger. В активити есть FragmentDialog, который вызывает intent камеры. После возвращения в активити database не инициализирована, хотя вызывается inject(), из за чего происходит краш приложения.

Код активити

```
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    (application as App).appComponent.userManager().userComponent?.inject(this)
        ...
        database.getReference("users")
   }
```

Comment: Так поле `database` покажите где и как инициализируете.